# Why do these twix range tests fail?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the twix library to check for clashing date ranges, yet nothing I do seems to trigger the checks. For example, here is the test I've been using:

```
eventTimeRange = moment("18-01-2018 02:00").twix("18-01-2018 03:00");
newEventTimeRange = moment("18-01-2018 02:00").twix("18-01-2018 03:00");
console.log(eventTimeRange.overlaps(newEventTimeRange)) //false
console.log(eventTimeRange.engulfs(newEventTimeRange)) //false
console.log(eventTimeRange.equals(newEventTimeRange)) //false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Because your input is not in ISO 8601 compliant format.

See [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and twix's [Inputs accepted](http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/docs.html#inputs-accepted).

Here a live sample:

```js
eventTimeRange = moment("18-01-2018 02:00", 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm').twix("18-01-2018 03:00", 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
newEventTimeRange = moment("18-01-2018 02:00", 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm').twix("18-01-2018 03:00", 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(eventTimeRange.overlaps(newEventTimeRange)) // true
console.log(eventTimeRange.engulfs(newEventTimeRange))  // true
console.log(eventTimeRange.equals(newEventTimeRange))   // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twix.js/1.2.1/twix.min.js"></script>
```